# Is there a fixed way to tell if $x^y-1$ is divisible by another number $z$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

$x, y$ and $z$ are all arbitrary numbers which can be anything. Is there a method to work it out?

Comment: Might https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation be helpful?

Comment: Hey do you have a list of already made examples?

Comment: $x^y-1=(x-1)(x^{y-1}+x^{y-2}+ . . . +1)$ so z must divide $x-1$ or other factor. for example $z=4$ divides $5^y-1$.

Comment: Trivially, if $x$ is odd then $z=2$ (if $y $ odd) or $z=4$ (if $y $ even).

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I think I understand the problem much better now. There is no straight answer, but in most cases it can be worked out.